# C loop not formatting correctly with array

Tags: arrays, c, loops

So, I tried to modify this code from [Samfoundry](https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-fcfs-scheduling/?fbclid=IwAR0yrTg82nQBNXjxJgozARwPbJWauWbYt3xJ5Af1KswiuqQcZPiKrH7E7PU) of a FCFS Scheduler. I removed the things pertaining to the turnaround time as I don't really need it and modified it so it can process elements already inside of an array instead of a user input. I think the logic is correct, but the formatting is not, and I don't really know why even when it's almost identical with the source code.

```
int main()
{
    int pid[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int bt[5] = {5, 3, 1, 2, 3};
    int n = 5;
 
    int i, wt[n];
    wt[0]=0;
 
    //for calculating waiting time of each process
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        wt[i]= bt[i-1]+ wt[i-1];
    }
 
    printf("Process ID      Burst Time     Waiting Time\n");
    float twt=0.0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t\t", pid[i]);
        printf("%d\t\t", bt[i]);
        printf("%d\t\t", wt[i]);
 
        //for calculating total waiting time
        twt += wt[i];

    }
    float awt;
 
    //for calculating average waiting time
    awt = twt/n;

    printf("\nAvg. waiting time= %f\n",awt);
}
```

```
Expected output: 
ProcessID       BurstTime     WaitingTime
1               5             0
2               3             5
3               1             8
4               2             9
5               1             11


Actual output: 
ProcessID       BurstTime     WaitingTime
1               5               0               2               3               5               3               1               8               4               2               9           5
3               11
```

Comment: Also note that tab often is a very bad formatting tool, use specific field-widths in your format strings instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the expected output is what I am expected to see, and the actual output is the output I had when I ran it if that's what you're asking

Comment: In the expected output, there is a newline after each three values on a line. Where do you print your newline?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added a newline on the third printf on the main loop and it worked now, thanks lmao if that's what you want me to do. but the reference code has no extra newline on it so i'm confused

Comment: In the example code there is a `printf("\n");` after the printing of the turn-around time. ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah i see now. I removed it as I thought I didn't need it and it turns out I did.

Answer (score 2):

Everything works fine in code you just need to add some extra tab spaces and new line character inside the for loop  change

```
printf("%d\t\t\t\t", pid[i]); //add two more tab spaces

printf("%d\t\t\t\t", bt[i]); //same as here add two tab spaces

printf("%d\t\t\n", wt[i]);  // add a \n i.e new line
```